# creating docker file to run selenium Javascript based tests

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I am trying to create a docker file to run selenium tests for a java script based  project. Below is my docker file so far:

```
#base image
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

#access to the project within docker container - Bundle app source
COPY  ./seleniumTest/project  /app

# Install Node.js
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install --yes curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -

#binding
EXPOSE 8080

#Define runtime  
ENTRYPOINT /app/login.test.js
```

while building and running the docker image as: `$ docker run -p 4000:8080 dockertest2` returns  `/bin/sh: 1: /app/login.test.js: Permission denied`

why is the permission denied for it?   **P.S:** I have changed to the dir which contains both Dockerfile and automation test JS files using (`cd dir`).

Answer (score 0):

Create a Docker Container with all the dependencies needed for you app to run
Which can be specified in the DockerFile.

Attached a script at Entry point to Start Selenium Server Standalone.

Build and Run your Container and Remember to Bind and Expose the port your selenium is running

Comment: As a dependency other than "FROM selenium/standalone-chrome"  as a base image, how can i figure out what else might be required?

Comment: what do you mean by binding in this case? Is it getting an access to the project I want to use into the docker file and run?

Comment: You need to build a container of your own to achieve what you want with all the dependencies needed for your app tests to run.
Binding means exposing a port and binding it to a locally accessible one where you are hosting your container or docker engine.

I am not very sure you know what you are actually doing from the command mentioned in the question as this requires knowledge on how you build a container based on your DockerFile specification

Comment: yes i didn't have clear idea on steps, just started to learn on it from last 2-3 days. I did some research and has created a docker file as attached in my question with some dependencies that  I thought  it requires and also binded it . could figure out why am i getting a permission denied?

Comment: Please check user's permission